How to recreate browser zoom in a react project
I'm searching for a zoom that works exactly the browser's zoom.
I've tried some but in the 3D viewer (three.js) the zoom is breaking the page.
I have to set the zoom at 80%, doing it directly from the browser Zoom perfectly works but setting it from code works for all the pages excluding the 3d viewer
i'v tried with
zoom: 0.8;

transform: scale(0.5)

document.body.style.zoom = "80%"


Do you mean to zoom the page or the scene? To "zoom" inside the scene, you'd have to move the camera in the scene (which is completely unrelated to the page). Your attempts so far only affect the page.

I mean the page because the container with the zoom at 80% doesn't cover 100% of the page. (For example in /home 80% zoom looks good and the page covers the 100% of the screen and the same for other routes. In /viewer the container turns to 80% and doesn't cover all the page anymore.)
Idk if if I managed to explain myself

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Solved!
I modified the CSS body zoom to 0.8. I've created an ID for the viewer container, and from CSS put the zoom to 1.25
